# Using the null value over a date value

Tags: t-sql, null

I have to select a group of records by Max(StartDate) and where there are multiple records with the same StartDate but Different EndDate I want to choose the record with the NULL EndDate over the value with an actual date.

```
SELECT UPC, DocumentNumber, MAX(StartDate) AS 'StartDate'
                FROM #tbDupRecs
                --WHERE EndDate = CASE EndDate WHEN NULL THEN NULL ELSE EndDate END
            GROUP BY UPC, DocumentNumber
            Order By UPC, DocumentNumber, StartDate
```

I get errors when I try to include something like EndDate as I cannot have it in the Select statement or the Group By, etc... Everything I tried (as above) picks the record with the date....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work... it gives a RN to each group of records you grouped by and gets the top one.

```
with cte as(
SELECT 
    UPC, 
    DocumentNumber, 
    StartDate,
    row_number over (partition by UPC, DocumentNumber order by case when StartDate is null then '12/31/2999' else StartDate end desc) as rn
FROM #tbDupRecs)

select * from cte where rn = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    UPC, 
    DocumentNumber, 
    StartDate
FROM #tbDupRecs
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT UPC, DocumentNumber, max(isnull(StartDate,'12/31/2999')) FROM #tbDupRecs group by UPC, DocumentNumber)
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    r.UPC, 
    r.DocumentNumber, 
    r.StartDate
FROM #tbDupRecs r
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT UPC, DocumentNumber, max(isnull(StartDate,'12/31/2999')) 
    FROM #tbDupRecs 
    group by UPC, DocumentNumber) r2 on r.UPC = r2.UPC and r.DocumentNumber = r2.DocumentNumber and isnull(r.StartDate,'12/31/2999') = isnull(r2.StartDate,'12/31/2999')
```

Comment: Thanks scsimon, where EndDate is Null I still have to return a Null value, not something like '12/31/2999'.

Comment: @TiltingCode these three options should do that

Comment: Did you run any of these solutions @TiltingCode